# Baking bevel node results in colourful normal map

Tags: normals, baking

I am trying to bake the bevel nodes normals onto my model. However, I constantly get results like this were the normal map looks all colourfull, instead of the light purple colour its supposed to be.
I've tried to do it using a duplicate of this model with the bevel node, and baking it from there. This unfortunately also gives the same result. I also tried CPU instead of GPU compute, Cuda instead of Optix, 2.92 instead of 2.93, using a cage, checking the normals and adding a displacement modifier to a duplicate, trying to bake that.
[grenade_normal.blend](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ao8EYxX_aCncneUtKMUt8GOkqfK2gA)
[image: Screenshot showing colourful normals]

Comment: Have you tried to turn off denoising (Optix) and bake on the CPU? It works for me that way.

Comment: I eventually got it working by importing it in a new file, despite it not working earlier. Thanks though for the suggestion Blendur! I can't answer you directly but trying to render it on the CPU didn't work for me when I tried.

Comment: That's weird that you had to import it in a new file. But I'm glad it works now. (You should be able to comment on your own question even with only 1 reputation. With 50 rep. you can comment on any question IIRC)